# Interquartile range when back-transformed mean on log-scale is not equal to median on normal scale

Tags: logarithm, range, interquartile

I have 2x10 observations that follow a non-normal distribution. They are perfectly distributed on log-scale.

From what I've learned, the back-transformation of the mean on log-scale should be a "good enough" median on normal scale.

However, with 10 observations, these two are not exactly equal (390 vs 440). I am using Stata.
I now need to report the IQR of the median, but I only know how to get the IQR of the median from normal scale, not the median from the back-transformed mean on log-scale.

I am thinking that these two should be the same? Can I just use the IQR from the normal scale, or would that not "align" with my back-transformed median?

Thanks!

Comment: What is "the IQR of the median"? The inter-quartile range is the distance between the first and the third quartile. (Of course this will be different between the original and the log-transformed data; I *hope* you are reporting on the original scale.) The median or mean does not enter into the "normal" IQR calculation at all.

Comment: The question seems a bit confused. There are at least two possible issues, (1) the consequences of transformation  followed by calculation as compared with the reverse; and (2) what you are assuming (hoping, trusting) to be true of the distribution as a hole.

Answer (score 1):

In principle, the logarithms of the median and quartiles of a variable with positive values are equal to the median and quartiles of the logarithms of that variable.

In practice, calculations involving interpolation may lead to some discrepancies, according to whether transformation is done first or second. The easiest example of this is the median of an even number of values, where it is a convention (some say rule) to take the median as the mean of the two middlemost values, occasionally called the comedians.

The auto data in Stata have 74 values for `price`. Access to Stata isn't needed to replicate this small finding: the median of logarithms can be different from the logarithm of the median. The two comedians are here 4934 and 5079 (USD).

```
. di (4934 + 5079) / 2
5006.5

. di ln(5006.5)
8.5184923

. mata : mean(ln((4934 \ 5039)))
  8.514434113

. mata : exp(mean(ln((4934 \ 5039))))
  4986.223621
```

The syntax here is that of Stata, but the calculation should be easy in any environment.

Here the discrepancy is small, but it can be much larger, even for data that would not be regarded as absurd or pathological. For variety we now use logarithms base 10. The median of 1, 10, 100, 1000 is 55, but the median of their logarithms to base 10 is the median of 0, 1, 2, 3 and so 1.5, which corresponds to about 32 on the original scale.

Quartiles again are often calculated by interpolation, and so the IQR will depend on the rules (or conventions) used, which are many. It's best to consult the documentation for your favourite software to find out what it supports, or to find a different favourite if your software is not adequately documented.

The same small pitfall exists for any nonlinear transformation.

NOTE: This answer does not explicitly or implicitly assume that the data follow any reference distribution, such as the lognormal, for which the median is the mean of the corresponding normal exponentiated. Whether that holds in practice with data depends largely on how close the data are to lognormal, as well as the general point above.